# KeyDown and KeyUp Events inside "Custom Control"

Tags: c#, wpf, controls

I have a custom control derived from control. The mouse events, such as `OnMouseLeftButtonDown (MouseButtonEventArgs e)`, can be used without any problems. Now I would like a combination of e.g. left-ctrl and left mouse click. But I just can't manage to respond to keyboard events in my "custom control".
Can someone give me a hint how to implement this?

This overriden method works fine.

```
protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(e);

    if (isKeyCtrlDown)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Test");
    }
}
```

And this overriden methods will not fired.

```
protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnKeyDown(e);

    if (e.Key == Key.LeftCtrl)
    {
        isKeyCtrlDown = true;
    }
}

protected override void OnKeyUp(KeyEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnKeyUp(e);

    if (Keyboard.IsKeyUp(Key.LeftCtrl))
    {
        isKeyCtrlDown = false;
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are there any other controls on your custom control?

Comment: Those will only fire if the control has focus.  Presuming it does, be aware they do not fire for [certain input keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.isinputkey?view=netframework-4.8).  Also it's possible a child control is setting `KeyEventArgs.Handled` to true.

Comment: You might be able to avoid the `OnKeyDown()` etc and instead in your mouse handler use `if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftCtrl) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightCtrl)) ...`

Comment: Oh mister Watson, that was so simple. thanks so mutch. And @Zer0, that is helpful for other solutions.